# Caching processed data in django

Tags: django, caching, django-models

I have a lot of energy measurement records stored in a Model.

My users need frequently access to a report of energy used, so a model.manager is in charged to query lot of records, apply an algorithm which takes ~2 seconds, which is lot of time, I tested memcached but with no luck because after a while the cached data is not available, but the users often back to see the same reports. So my potential solution to this performance issue is to store the processed data (not only the queryset but data queryset after algorithm application) in a model called "ProcessedData".

So when the user is prompt to access to energy report, the manager in charged will query first ProccessData and if `ProccessData.objects.filter(field1='field1').exist()`: the returned data will be directly passed to template for visualization. If data required has not been  previously required the manager in charged will have to apply algorithm and send request back to user.

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting something like this I would definitely give projects like [django-cache-machine](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine) or [johnny-cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/) a try, they do model caching and they do that nicely.

I think johnny cache it's the one fits better with your needs since it does never-expire queryset caching.

I am not sure what you mean with "cache data is unavailable", but is something you can easily solve in several ways (eg. using a persistent cache backend like redis).

This is another thing I would try before the database caching you're about to implement if you need something more than queryset caching.

Django cache utils comes with a nice cache decorator (the @cached) (see docs and example [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cache-utils)) which does caching based on parameters

Comment: When I process data using as input the result of a query I know that query and even the request that is sent to user is cached when I use memcache of johny-cache, the problem appears when that data is required 12 hours later of maybe a day, in that case and depending of the amount of database interaction with other users, the processed data that was cached initially is not available.

Comment: have you tried something like the @cached decorator of django-cache-utils ? combine that with a custom cache backend that does never-expire caching (johnny cache for instance does that since django does not support "forever") and you have persistent results caching